# Replacing json-encoded URL with mod_proxy_html

Tags: json, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy-html

I've currently installed a reverse proxy. An apache is doing this job. So I configured mod_proxy to adapt the urls. I also use mod_proxy_html to adapt HTML- and JavaScript-Links. Now I've got a problem with an ajax call which returns an json-encoded url.

Is there a way to do this with mod_proxy_html? 
Does anybody have a suggestion how to adapt those urls otherwise?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found another way to substitute the json-links:

I used the apache module **mod_substitute**.
If you declare *application/json* as OutputFilter, the Proxy will replace the links.
The syntax of mod_substitute resembles the syntax of the unix-/linux-command **sed**.

A little example:

`AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE application/json
Substitute "s|zuersetzen|ersetzt|n"`

Take the following link as reference:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_substitute.html